# Conversion from .NET 3.5 to .NET 2.0

Tags: .net-2.0, c#-2.0

How I can convert the following methods to C# 2.0?

```
    private static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return string.Join(string.Empty, bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
    }

    private static byte[] ToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length).
                 Where(x => 0 == x % 2).
                 Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16)).
                 ToArray();
    }
```

I haven't got experience with .NET 2.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    string s = ToHexString(new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15});
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    foreach (byte b in ToByteArray(s))
        Console.WriteLine(b);
}

private static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
    return sb.ToString();
}

private static byte[] ToByteArray(string hex)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[hex.Length/2];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        b[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i*2,2), 16);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this conversion yourself.  Obviously you'll want to convert it into a `for` loop.  `Enumerable.Range` essentially provides an `int[]` array upon which to loop.  After that, the `Where` equates to an `if` check, the `Select` is a transformation from the `int` to a substring and finally to a `byte`, and last, you stuff all that into an array, probably by adding them to a `List<byte>` declared outside the loop.  (and when you're done, you can call `ToArray` on the list)

I could provide a complete answer, but I think this sort of exercise is best left to you so you can learn from it.